# What if someone offers an bounty and waits to mark my solution as answer after the period is over

Tags: support, bounty

I am a little dissapointed. I took quite some effort (in multiple steps) to answer a technical question offering a bounty of "50". Although the answer was even days within the bounty-period  it was only marked as answer after the period was over. I cannot say if the person that asked was only too slow or if this was intended, but I belive if an answer was given within the period and accepted afterwards, one should receive the bounty.

I would not have takten the effort for just 15 Points... so what to do? Its about this question: [Implementing Editing AND Double Click (MouseDoubleClick) in WPF DataGrid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794969/implementing-editing-and-double-click-mousedoubleclick-in-wpf-datagrid/23904565#23904565)

Best regards
Gope

Comment: Maybe the person had a family/health/broken-computer issue... Impossible to know. But, yeah, I know the feeling of losing a bounty that seemed granted... Solution: grow a thick skin and never take a bounty for granted.

Comment: If you're in it for the rep, you will be left feeling very under-satisfied before too long.

Comment: However, I think the way Gope looks at the problem is very right. If an answer is WRITTEN in the "bounty period" and gets accepted after it, the answer's author should get the bounty nevertheless.

Comment: Such questions are generally answered/commented as *That's just the way it works*. I agree with *Maybe the person had a family/health/broken-computer issue* but not SO. And I completely agree with @OddDev. Answers given outside the bounty period should be ignored but those within the said period must get rewarded on acceptance. SO must consider this as Its becoming a common issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing you can do. If the bounty is over, the bounty is over. The person who offered it already gets a 24-hour grace period to award it (or even accept an answer) before it is completely gone. What you're suggesting is basically an infinite grace period, which doesn't make any sense at all. Might as well just make bounties permanent until the person gets the answer they want in that case.

It sucks, but that's just the way the system works.

Comment: That's the point. The grace-period is only for putting in answers I thought. The bounty should be awarded at any time an answer is marked that has been given within the period.
People can post high bounties and then not award the answer... that is not right... :( thanks for the 1+ though!

Comment: No, the 7 days that the bounty runs is the time to put in answers - that's the time the question is actively advertised as having a bounty. The grace period is a 24-hour period *after the bounty has expired* that the person gets to award it before it is completely gone.

Comment: Yes I understand that now, but its not right. You offer people a bounty, they do the work for you (IN TIME) and then you can just wait for the bounty to run out... That should not be an option!!! The Answer-Period can end like before... it offers people to cheat and some will just accidently not get their bounty. I believe that is not right.

Comment: And also as much as I appreciate you joining this topic, but even if it works that way... it can and should be changed IMHO.

Comment: Cheat? It's not like they get the bounty back if they don't award it. Would you still be complaining about this if he *hadn't* accepted your answer? What if he had just commented "thanks this worked" and did nothing? Should we explicitly go in and change it to award it to you? No. He didn't award it within the allotted timeframe, and you did not qualify for auto-award.

Comment: OK, wait. I am sorry. I did not know that he had to pay the bounty. I just checked and you are right. I did not care too much about receiving it, but the possibility of being able to offer something you don't have to pay for. One last question though. What is auto-award. This sounds like what I belive would be the right solution. If an answer that was given within the timeframe is afterwards marked the bounty should be awarded...

Comment: If you are marked as accepted during the bounty period, you receive the full bounty when the grace period expires (assuming the person didn't already award it). If your answer reaches a score of 2 and is the top voted answer, it will be awarded half the bounty when the grace period expires (again, assuming they didn't award it).

Comment: thank you for clarifying. Obviously in my case it was just an unlucky combination of circumstances...